# What is the difference between new and extra packages when running the command apt-get install in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

When I attempt to install a particular package I get the following output. I had a read of http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-depends however it is not clear whether `extra packages` are installed as they are dependencies and that the `New packages` are dependent upon the `extra packages`.

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass4 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbluray1 libcddb2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirac-encoder0 libdvbpsi7
  libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml3 libenca0 libfaad2 libgsm1 libiso9660-8
  libkate1 libmad0 libmatroska5 libmodplug1 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4
  libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2
  libsidplay2 libswscale2 libtar0 libtwolame0 libupnp3 libva-x11-1 libva1
  libvcdinfo0 libvlc5 libvlccore5 libvpx1 libx264-120 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 vlc-data
  vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
Suggested packages:
  libbluray-bdj libdvdcss2 debhelper fakeroot build-essential videolan-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libass4 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbluray1 libcddb2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdirac-encoder0 libdvbpsi7
  libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml3 libenca0 libfaad2 libgsm1 libiso9660-8
  libkate1 libmad0 libmatroska5 libmodplug1 libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4
  libpostproc52 libresid-builder0c2a libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2
  libsidplay2 libswscale2 libtar0 libtwolame0 libupnp3 libva-x11-1 libva1
  libvcdinfo0 libvlc5 libvlccore5 libvpx1 libx264-120 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 vlc
  vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

Answer (score 1):

new packages is everything that is being installed, even the dependencies.

extra packages are things that you did not type in to be installed, but are needed for the program you are installingto run/function (aka dependencies)

Comment: When you say everything do you mean the packages that are needed to run the application I want to install as well as any dependencies? If so would these include the extras?

Comment: ok. Ill try to make this a simple as possible